# Using Unix, How to rename a Autosys job?

Tags: unix, automation, scripting, autosys

Is it possible to rename a Autosys job name using Unix commands?

For example :
Change the name of Autosys job : Job_morning_A to Job_evening_A.. What and how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

you can create jil file like below
rename_job:oldjobname

new_name: newjobname

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to update a job name. In this case you have to delete the job using ‘delete_job’ and then run ‘insert_job’ with the updated name.

Answer (score 0):

An update to the topic: Since version 12, the vendor introduced rename_job subcommand. It has the following format:

rename_job: old_job_name
new_name: new_job_name

Limits: Up to 64 alphanumeric characters; can include the following characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, period (.), underscore (_), pound (#), colon (:), and hyphen (-); cannot include embedded spaces or tabs.

When a job which has multiple references from the other jobs is renamed, then all the jobs which have references to the renamed job will also be modified accordingly.
The user is notified with renamed jobs that have dependent conditions.

A job cannot be renamed when it is in either STARTING or RUNNING state.